# Prove that there is a positive integer $N$ such that $N^3$ ends in $S$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $d$ be a positive integer and let $S$ be a string of $d$ decimal digits ending in $1, 3, 7$ or $9$. Prove that there is a positive integer $N$ such that $N^3$ ends in $S$.

Let $S = \overline{a_da_{d-1} \ldots a_1}$ where $a_1 = 1,3,7,9$. Then we need to find a positive integer $N$ such that $$N^3 \equiv S \equiv 10^{d-1}a_d+10^{d-2}a_{d-1}+\cdots+a_1 \pmod{10^d}.$$ How can we continue?

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it would be sufficient to do it $\pmod{2^d}$ and $\pmod{5^d}$.  For those - do you know Hensel's lemma?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, but how do we use Hensel's lemma here?

Comment: Use it to prove $x^3 - S$ has a root in both $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Then the result follows by Hensel's lemma?

Comment: Well, for example, once you've proved $x^3 - S$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ (to be clear, this is the 5-adic integers, not the integers $\pmod{5}$), then $\mathbb{Z} / 5^d \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5 / 5^d \mathbb{Z}_5$, so $x^3 - S$ also has a root in $\mathbb{Z} / 5^d \mathbb{Z}$.